# Help desk cannot respond to UAC prompts over Remote Assistance

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I'm trying to use the in-built Remote Assistance (RA) software in Windows 7 to support my users.  I initiate a RA session with the user and ask to remotely control their desktop.  They tick a little check box that says something to the effect of 'allow helper to respond to UAC prompts' and it **pops up with a UAC prompt**.

The user cannot respond to the UAC prompt because they're not a local administrator - I am.  Isn't that what that little check box is for???

I've found [this on TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistasetup/thread/1ac19761-3522-497d-be45-12e211c0ff5b) from back in '07 on Vista.

From what I've found, I could disable UAC (terrible idea) or make all my users local administrators on their computers (yet another terrible idea).

I'm hoping that MS has fixed this little oversight in Windows 7.  Remote Assistance is completely useless to me if I can't respond to UAC prompts with my username and password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Windows 7 added enough options in Group Policy to get around this. Look at the choices found here: **Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options** with the prefix *User Account Control...*.

I think the one you're looking for is **User Account Control: Allow UIAccess applications to prompt for elevation without using the secure desktop.**

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/User-Account-Control-Allow-UIAccess-applications-to-prompt-for-elevation-without-using-the-secure-desktop

Comment: YYYYYYYYEEEEEEEEESSSSSSS. This was the answer.  Thank you guys so much